# Optgroup dynamic with javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, optgroup

I am trying to create  dynamic. I fetch data with an ajax request and want to display it sorted. It will also receive the category name.  My current result is that it is sorting but it is making a new optgroup instead of adding it to the old one
 (https://i.imgur.com/P3oGXKl.gifv)

```
$.each(response, function(index, value) {

  if (value['categories_name'] != current_sub) {
    console.log(current_sub);
    if (current_sub) {
      tr += '</optgroup>'
    }
    tr += "<optgroup label='" + value['categories_name'] + "'>";
    current_sub = value['categories_name'];

  }

  tr += '<option value="' + value['product_id'] + '">' + value['product_name'] + '</option>';
});
tr += '</optgroup>';
```

Comment: may you add some HTML and response value? Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion: first put you data inside a categorized structure (like `{ category_name: [...] }`), then generate your HTML. In this way will be easier.